# Microcontroller GPIO input voltage limit

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, gpio

I was looking at a [datasheet for a microcontroller](https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/EFM32TG110.pdf) and noticed that, under its section for GPIO input voltage (p.14), there is no listed maximum for the high input, only a minimum. Does this indicate that, ensuring I keep current below the maximum (which I would assume to be 20mA from the current sink specs), I would be able to put any voltage through the pin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Max voltage on any I/O pin **Vdd+0.3**

[image]

A logic high is whenever the voltage on the input pin >=  0.7Vdd
A logic low is whenever the voltage on the input is <= 0.3Vdd